# Is it possible to set to null an instance of a class within the class

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is it possible to set to null an instance of a class within the class. For example, could I do something like this

```
int main{
    //Create a new test object
    Test test = new Test();
    //Delete that object. This method should set the object "test" to null, 
    //thus allowing it to be called by the garbage collector.
    test.delete();

}


public class Test{

    public delete(){
        this = null;
    }
}
```

I have tried this and it does not work. Using "this = null" I get the error that the left hand side needs to be a variable. Is there a way to achieve something similar?

Comment: Any reason why you want to set it to null? Garbage collectors are smart. They know when an object is no longer reachable. Are you trying to kill *all* references to this object?

Comment: No you can do `test = null;` in your main. Although this is unnecessary in most situations as the GC will collect your object as soon as it is "collectable".

Comment: You're trying to "destroy" the object.  That cannot be done until ALL references to the object are gone.  Best you can do is put a "deleted" flag in the object which causes all calls on it to fail.

Comment: @user414076 Just for convenience. Instead of having multiple lines of code that remove all references within the class and set the object itself to null, I'd like to have all the dereferencing happen in one spot.

Comment: I bet there's some weird way to do this with Reflection.  Somehow find the object reference higher up the stack, get its name, and set it to null.  Not really a good use case for it, but I'd be interested in seeing it done just because.

Comment: @rioneye Why do you want to set the object to null in the first place? There really are very few situations when this is necessary.

Comment: @HotLicks How would you know if the object was called? Assuming there are more than one method/field.

Comment: @rioneye, the question really is *why* are you setting it to null. The objects inside the instance belong to the instance. The instance, if not rooted, is eligible for collection, along with its state. Is there more to this story of yours? Setting an object reference to null is generally not necessary.

Comment: @assylias Isn't it necessary to remove all references to an object for garbage collection? The 'test' object is a reference to the object so wouldn't that need to be set to null?

Comment: @rioneye As soon as the method exits, the object will be eligible for GC if it was only referenced by a local variable.

Comment: "How would you know if the object was called?"  Well, you put code in each method to test.  And make access to fields private.

Comment: @HotLicks I guess I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: It is quite elegant -- the object just goes away as soon as you don't need it anymore, no effort required.

Comment: You can also have a level of indirection.  Have an object that contains a reference to your object, and clear the reference when you want to "delete" it.  But this requires all users to fetch the pointer from the first object for every use and not somehow "cache" it between uses.

Comment: The "test" reference (it's not an object but a reference to an object) is "automatic" and goes away as soon as the containing method exits.  It does not need to be set to null.

Comment: "Instead of having multiple lines of code that remove all references within the class and set the object itself to null" -- maybe this is your point of confusion.  You don't have explicitly null 99.9% of the references.  Rather, they "go away" one way or another -- the containing object is GCed, the containing method exits, etc.  Only in a few cases (eg, a large array of references where objects may be "discarded" but still referenced from the array) do you need to explicitly null anything..

Comment: I strongly feel this should be allowed, like I am fetching some objects from DB, now before returning the object should check itself and get null on certain conditions. I know we can add some additional code to validate the collection, anyhow if it's happening in multiple places., we need to repeat it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An instance of an object doesn't know which references might be referring to it, so there's no way that code within the object can null those references.  What you're asking for isn't possible(*).

* <sub>at least not without adding a pile of scaffolding to keep track of all the references, and somehow inform their owners that they should be nulled - in no way would it be "Just for convenience".</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
public class WrappedTest {
    private Test test;
    public Test getTest() { return test; }
    public void setTest(Test test) { this.test = test; }
    public void delete() { test = null; }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only one instance of the object, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: @rioneye You would instantiate a new instance of `WrappedTest` for each `Test` that you wanted to be able to delete; `test` is an instance variable, not a static variable, so each `WrappedTest` gets its own `Test`

Answer (score 0):

"`this`" is a final variable. you can not assign any values to it.

If you want to set the reference null you can do this

```
test = null;
```

Comment: Right, but is there a way to achieve as equivalent result?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the instance of your class. When you modify a reference variable, it only modifies *that* reference and *nothing* else. For example:

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = a;

a = new Integer(2);      //does NOT modify variable b

System.out.println(b);   //prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Is it possible to set to null an instance of a class within the class?.`

You cannot do this from the member methods of the same instance. So, `this=null` or that sort of thing will not work.

**How come one set an instance to an null?**

That question itself is wrong, we set references to `null` but not instances. Unused objects automatically garbage collected in java.

If you set `test=null` it will eventually gets garbage collected.

```
 int main{
    //Create a new test object
    Test test = new Test();
    // use the object through test
    test=null;
}
```